# Change class attribute based on current view/controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What I need to do is pretty simple, but an elegant way to do it is escaping me, as I'm a noob to Rails. Basically, I need to change the body tag's class attribute, which resides in my application.html.erb file, based on which view is currently being shown.

So, on my index page it would be:

```
<body class="pull_top">
```

but on any other page (so far), it will just be

```
<body>
```

My first thought was to add this to application_helper.rb

```
  def body_class
    default_class = ""
    if current_page?(controller: 'index')
      default_class = "pull_top"
    end
    default_class
  end
```

then do

```
<body class="<%= body_class %>">
```

but then on all other pages besides index I'd end up with

```
<body class="">
```

which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body <%= controller_name == 'index' ? "class='pull_top'" : '' %>>
```

Comment: I heard somewhere that it's bad form to put logic in your views. That's why I avoided it.

Comment: You can move this controller_name == 'index' ? "class='pull_top'" : '' to a helper method. I was just showing you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion ending up with:

```
<body class="">
```

is not really a big deal.  The logic is being encapsulated within the helper and you still have the ability to add additional classes to the `<body>` tag that could apply in both of the scenarios that you had described.  For instance:

```
<body class="<%= body_class %> pretty_style another_style">
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can put in your application.html.erb the following:

```
<body class="<%= yield :body_class %>">
...
</body>
```

and then, in your specific views that you actually want a class:

```
provide(:body_class, 'whatever-you-want')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def body_class
  default_class = nil
  if current_page?(controller: 'index')
    default_class = "pull_top"
  end
  default_class
end
```

view:

```
<body<%= " class=\"#{body_class}\"" if body_class %>>
```

the problem here is body_class will be called twice

Answer (score 0):

You can put if statement if body_class present than apply class otherwise you can leave it as it is like:

```
<% if body_class.present? %>
  <body class="<%= body_class %>">
<% else %>
  <body>
<% end %>
```